# Heroku server - Rails View errors but the code runs fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a snippet of code that takes quite a while to run - About two minutes. Locally, when this code is initiated through a button in my view, the page just appears to be loading until the two minutes is up.

When I deployed this to heroku, the code was erroring out. I changed my Unicorn timeout time to allow for the code to finish, and now when looking at my logs the code is completing just fine.

However, I am presented with this error in my heroku app's view:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

How can I get the same behavior I have locally on my heroku app? I would prefer that the page just continue to appear as if it were loading until the code is complete.

## EDIT

I'm seeing this in my logs:

```
 2014-01-14T17:11:49.388634+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
 method=POST path=/fluidsurveys/test_send_file host=glacial-spire-1431.herokuapp.com 
fwd="66.195.31.22" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=30090ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Comment: What does `heroku logs` return?

Comment: it returns the body of my code snippet succeeding. It never actually returns an error, it looks just like the local development logs which work just fine.

Comment: Yes, but the error might occur before your snippet succeeded. (Usually when it happens to me it means I forgot run migrations)

Comment: @BroiSatse Correct you are - I'm seeing an H12 error in my logs about halfway through the code running. It looks like this times out at 30 seconds, and is not configurable. Perhaps I should look at putting this task into a background process instead.